# Including dependencies in c++ dll project results in a broken DLL build

Tags: c++, dll, dependencies, include

I am making an injectable DLL file that uses the Lua C API. I was following the following tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4l5HdmPoynw&ab_channel=javidx9 on how to embed Lua into C++ and decided to embed Lua into an injectable DLL. The DLL works just fine until I use code from the Lua C API. Visual Studio isn't helping me, because it acts like nothing is wrong in the DLL. Am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
//dllmain.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
extern "C" {
#include "lua542/include/lua.h"
#include "lua542/include/lauxlib.h"
#include "lua542/include/lualib.h"
}

#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma comment(lib, "lua542/liblua54.a")
#endif

bool was_pressed = false;

bool IsKeyPressed()
{
    bool is_pressed = (GetAsyncKeyState(0x4A) & 0x8000) != 0;

    if (!was_pressed && is_pressed)
    {
        was_pressed = is_pressed;
        return true;
    }

    was_pressed = is_pressed;
    return false;
}

DWORD WINAPI TestThread(HMODULE hModule) {
    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
    while (true) {
        //Activates on pressing key "J"
        if (IsKeyPressed()) {
            std::string cmd = "a = 7 + 11";
            luaL_openlibs(L);
            luaL_dostring(L, cmd.c_str());
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Test", "Test", MB_OK);
        CloseHandle(CreateThread(nullptr, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)TestThread, hModule, 0, nullptr));
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

I tried to keep the Lua library folder in the same folder of the DLL file, but the file was still not functional. I was expecting the DLL to work just fine and to work with its dependencies, because Visual Studio acted like nothing was wrong.

I'm not sure if this as something to do with the problem, but I am currently using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: please read this first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices

Comment: You need to edit your post and include the details of what and how it's failing, what behavior you are expecting and what behavior you're experiencing. Simply saying it stops working isn't at all helpful. i.e. how do you know it's not working?

Comment: I forgot to mention that when using Process Hacker 2 to inject the DLL, the test dialogue box will appear, but when I used code from the lua library, no dialogue box appeared upon injection. I even looked at the properties of the test process that I injected, and the DLL file that I made was not there, meaning that my code probably has something invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found what the problem was (I feel a little stupid after realizing this). I first have to inject the library DLL that I was using, then I can inject my DLL. This way, my target application has the library prepared for and DLLs that may require said library. Also, thanks to engf-010, I realized that I was using a risky method of using CreateThread in my DllMain. For now, I'm going to inject the library DLL manually, but I might add code that does it automatically (although that might flag it as a virus, so I'm a little conflicted on that). Thanks for the help guys!